# k is algebraically closed in field of fractions of k-domain that admits $k$ morphism to $k$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $A$ be a $k$ algebra for $k$ a field. Moreover, let $A$ be a domain. Suppose there exists a $k$-algebra-homomorphism $A\to k$. I want to prove that $k$ is algebraically closed in $K:=$Quot$(A)$ the field of fractions of $A$.

I tried to prove this in the following way:
Let $C$ be the integral closure of $k$ in $K$. Then $k':=C\cap A$ is a subring of a domain and therefore a domain. Since it is also integral over the field $k$, we conclude that $k'$ is a field. By assumption, we get a map $k'\to A \to k$ and therefore $k'=k$. So $C\cap A = k$. I am stuck here.

Context: I'm trying to prove that a connected group scheme $G$ over Spec$(k)$, which is separated, of finite type and geometrically reduced over Spec$(k)$ is geometrically irreducible/connected. This can be shown by proving that $k$ is integrally closed in $k(G)$, the residue field at the generic point, see stack project. I am trying to use an affine open neighbourhood $U$ of the neutral element $e: \text{Spec}(k)\to G$ to get $U=\text{Spec}(A)$ and use the above result.

I could use the assumptions that $A$ is finitely generated or the geometrically reduced assumption but I don't know how they could help.

Comment: I understand it as "let $A$ be an integral domain containing a field $k$, if there is a $k$-homomorphism $f:A\to k$ then every element of $A-k$ is transcendental over $k$".

The proof is immediate: if $a\in A$ is algebraic over $k$ then $f$ restricts to a $k$-homomorphism $k[a]\to k$. 

$k[a]$ is a field so $f|_{k[a]}$ is injective ie. $\dim_k(k[a])\le 1$ which implies that $\dim_k(k[a])=1,a\in k$.

Comment: @reuns I want to show that every element of Quot$(A)-k$ is transcendental over $k$. I get your prove for showing that every element of $A-k$ is transcendental over $k$. I believe that also follows from what I wrote down. But my problem is i don't know how I can conclude that elements $a/b$ for $a, b \in A$ can't be algebraic over $k$.

Comment: My bad. Well $A=\Bbb{R}[t,it]$ has an homomorphism to $\Bbb{R}$ and its quotient field contains $i$

Comment: @reuns You're right, thanks

Comment: @reuns i answered what you wrote to accept the answer and remove this question from the list of unanswered questions. But I cannot accept it yet by some rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reuns commented the following

> Well $A=\mathbb{R}[t,it]$ has an homomorphism to $\mathbb R$ and its quotient field contains $i$.